# why attach to window [edited]

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I was looking over the code for qunit.

My question is why would you want to attach the qunit object via property to window object.

Here is the link to the [file](http://github.com/gutzofter/qunit/blob/master/qunit/qunit.js). Look at line 11.

If I look at a unit test run using firebug you can see it is a property of window.

[edit]
Additional: Is there a specific reference for best practice for declaring things in specific namespaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All global objects (functions, variables, etc) are just children of window, it's the default context.

For example: `window.jQuery` or `window.$`

It may be easier to think of it this way...where else would you put them?  When you're doing something this general, best (or at least easiest) to stick them in the default place.  If you're doing something complex with lots of functions, objects, etc...best to put them in a namespace or within an object.  For example all of jQuery's code is under `jQuery`, not littered in the root of the DOM like `window.ajax`, instead it's `jQuery.ajax`.

This is much neater, but perhaps overkill when you're dealing with a few items, but it's a good idea to make sure they are unique if this is the case...which qunit does, by prefixing their objects with `qunit-`

Comment: so initially you would start off in the window namespace and add properties to it?

Comment: so I checked out this very same page. and noticed that there is both window.jQuery and window.$ properties. Isn't one an alias for the other? Has jQuery actually loaded both properies or r they pointers to the same memory? Is there some way to find the memory address in firebug?

Comment: @Gutzofter  - Yes, `window.$` is an alias for `window.jQuery` so your code can be shorter, e.g. `$(selector)` instead of `jQuery(selector)`  I'm not sure of a way to find the actual memory address, sorry :)  For the other question, yes you start with window, add something there (like say the jQuery object) then you can add to that.

Answer (score 3):

Attaching globals as properties of `window` is bad practice.  All globals should be declared using `var`.  Here's my reasons:

1. It makes static analysis of source code much harder.  It is impossible to tell from looking at a script which globals will be declared and when.  Undeclared globals *will* create `ReferenceError`s if they're used.  Using `var` means JavaScript's hoisting takes effect, and mitigates this problem.
2. Globals made this way are fundamentally different, and there is no easy way for your code to detect this.  The biggest difference is the absence of `[[DontDelete]]` on globals made this way, which means you can delete your global variables.  This is silly.
3. It will tempt you to declare your globals from outside the global scope.  This is *magic*, and bad magic at that.  Don't do it.

As far as I'm concerned, the fact that `window.x = 1` creates a global variable named `x` is an interesting curiosity of JavaScript, but should not be used nor replied upon.  There are, however, good reasons to use properties of `window`, since it's an object like any other (more or less).  In these cases, you should use the full name, e.g. `window.onload` instead of just `onload`.

Comment: "Undeclared globals will create ReferenceErrors if they're used." Correct yet incorrect.  If you do benny = undefinedvar; benny's type will become "undefined" ... If you do benny = undefinedvar.anothervar; it will throw because you are attempting to access a property of undefined.

Comment: I suppose that was unclear.  By "used" I mean used in an expression, rather than used as an lvalue (i.e. in an assignment).

Also, running `x = y` throws a `ReferenceError: y is not defined`.

Comment: what static analysis tools specifically are you using?

Comment: I don't even mean using any particular tool.  Just looking at the code, it won't always be immediately clear what globals exist and when.  Although I believe that tools like JSLint will get tripped up by this.  Can be mitigated by using a `/*globals */` comment, of course, but it's not really an argument for using window-prop globals.